# Algorithm for finding the largest K numbers in a max heap of size N in O(K) time?

Tags: algorithm

The [O(K * logK) algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209556/print-the-biggest-k-elements-in-a-given-heap-in-oklogk) for finding the largest K numbers in a max heap of size N is well known. I heard about that there is an O(K) algorithm for solving this problem. I do not find the literature on this. Could anyone give any pointers on this?  Thanks!

Comment: @yuyang do you mean the k largest in unsorted manner because sorted would mean you can sort the array in O(n) because building heap is O(n) and sorting array in O(n) using comparison is impossible.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question over at cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's due to Frederickson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014892/simple-explanation-of-fredericksons-heap-selection-algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally find the paper that describes the algorithm. There is a similar question on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Data-Structures/Given-a-min-heap-of-N-elements-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-K-smallest-elements-of-the-heap-in-O-K-time).

The paper, "[An Optimal Algorithm for Selection in a Min-Heap](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540183710308)", by G.N. Frederickson, describes the algorithm. The following is the abstract:

An O(k)-time algorithm is presented for selecting the kth smallest element in a binary min-heap of size n⪢k. The approach uses recursively defined data structures that impose a hierarchical grouping on certain elements in the heap. The result establishes a further example of a partial order for which the kth smallest element can be determined in time proportional to the information theory lower bound. Two applications, to a resource allocation problem and to the enumeration of the k smallest spanning trees, are identified.

Comment: Do you plan to describe on a high-level how the algorithm works? That would certainly be interesting.

Comment: @NiklasB. Unfortunately, the algorithm Frederickson describes is extremely hard to describe at a high level due to its complexity.  His first algorithm SEL1 can be described at a high level with rigorous explanation, and it only gets more complex as he continues to revise that initial approach.

Comment: I figured as much... It's also entirely impractical from what I understand.