# What is the time complexity of heapq.nlargest?

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, time-complexity

I was looking at [this pycon talk, 34:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYlnfvKVDoM&feature=emb_err_woyt) and the speaker says that getting the `t` largest elements of a list of `n` elements can be done in `O(t + n)`.

How is that possible? My understanding is that creating the heap will be `O(n)`, but what's the complexity of `nlargest` itself, is it `O(n + t)` or `O(t)` (and what's the actual algorithm)?

Comment: You might be interested in [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py#l195).

Comment: If you want it in sorted order, obviously that's not going to happen in linear time. Otherwise, you could call `nlargest` with `t=n` to comparison sort a list in linear time. If you just want the `t` largest elements in *any* order, that can be done in O(n) with [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). `heapq.nlargest` doesn't use quickselect, though; it gives the items in sorted order with a heap-based algorithm.

Comment: Just a general note: The claim that it takes time O(t + n) itself strikes me as wary, because that is just O(n). It's not technically incorrect but somewhat strange to express it that way

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The speaker is wrong in this case.  The actual cost is `O(n * log(t))`.  Heapify is called only on the first `t` elements of the iterable.  That's `O(t)`, but is insignificant if `t` is much smaller than `n`.  Then all the remaining elements are added to this "little heap" via `heappushpop`, one at a time.  That takes `O(log(t))` time per invocation of `heappushpop`.  The length of the heap remains `t` throughout.  At the very end, the heap is sorted, which costs `O(t * log(t))`, but that's also insignificant if `t` is much smaller than `n`.

### Fun with Theory ;-)

There are reasonably easy ways to find the t'th-largest element in expected `O(n)` time; for example, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_selection).  There are harder ways to do it in worst-case `O(n)` time.  Then, in another pass over the input, you could output the `t` elements >= the t-th largest (with tedious complications in case of duplicates).  So the whole job *can* be done in `O(n)` time.

But those ways require `O(n)` memory too.  Python doesn't use them.  An advantage of what's actually implemented is that the worst-case "extra" memory burden is `O(t)`, and that can be very significant when the input is, for example, a generator producing a great many values.

Comment: Great that makes sense; I was really hoping `O(t + n)` was right though, I thought I'd learn about some new heap wizardry :)

Comment: See the edit just now for an O(n) method - but it has nothing to do with heaps, alas.

Comment: Fun fact: You *can* in fact heapify the array in O(n) and fetch the top-k of the resulting heap in O(k) time per query. It's highly non-trivial though and the `heapq` module does not implement it. (It also probably has gigantic constant factors that make it infeasible in practice)

Comment: @NiklasB. where can I read about this `O(k)` algorithm? Even if non-trivial I'm super interested!

Comment: @foo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574580/algorithm-for-finding-the-largest-k-numbers-in-a-max-heap-of-size-n-in-ok-time

Comment: @NiklasB. my guess is that will require `O(n+t)` in space vs the `heapq` which just uses `O(t)` in space, when `t<<n` and `n` is coming from a generator we save a lot of space for almost equal runtimes. Not sure if it makes sense to have a non default option to avoid the sort at the end if the caller doesn't really care about the `t` elements being sorted.

Comment: I think adding remaining elements to the "little heap" costs O((n-t)log(t)), and the sorting at the very end takes O(t log(t)). Neither is ignored at last. They sum up to O(n log(t)). Am I right?

Answer (score 8):

For Heapq t largest or t smallest, the time complexity will be `O(nlog(t))`

Heapq will build the heap for the first t elements, then later on it will iterate over the remaining elements by pushing and popping the elements from the heap (maintaining the t elements in the heap).

1. For building the heap for first t elements will be done `tlog(t)`
2. For pushing and popping, the remaining elements will be done in
   `(n-t)log(t)`
3. The overall time complexity will be `nlog(t)`

Answer (score 2):

It's actually O(n+t*log(n)) because heapify takes O(n) and for every element of largest or smallest takes O(log(n)). So for t largest/smallest it takes t*log(n). Therefore time complexity will be O(n+t*log(n))

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments in the [heapq source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/heapq.py#L412):

```
# Algorithm notes for nlargest() and nsmallest()
# ==============================================
#
# Make a single pass over the data while keeping the k most extreme values
# in a heap.  Memory consumption is limited to keeping k values in a list.
#

# Theoretical number of comparisons for k smallest of n random inputs:
#
# Step   Comparisons                  Action
# ----   --------------------------   ---------------------------
#  1     1.66 * k                     heapify the first k-inputs
#  2     n - k                        compare remaining elements to top of heap
#  3     k * (1 + lg2(k)) * ln(n/k)   replace the topmost value on the heap
#  4     k * lg2(k) - (k/2)           final sort of the k most extreme values
#
# Combining and simplifying for a rough estimate gives:
#
#        comparisons = n + k * (log(k, 2) * log(n/k) + log(k, 2) + log(n/k))
```