# What is the time complexity of getting first n largest elements in min heap?

Tags: python

Given that heapq in python is min heap as specified in python doc, assume that I have a heapq with m elements, what is the time complexity of calling nlargest? I don't think the complexity is O(n*lg(m)) because simply popping the root and heapify again in a min heap only get you nsmallest?

[How does heapq.nlargest work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038756/how-does-heapq-nlargest-work)

Answer (score 9):

You can see the code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py). Suppose you do a `heapq.nlargest(n, it)`, where `it` is an iterable with `m` elements.
It first constructs a min heap with the first `n` elements of `it`. Then, for the rest `m-n` elements, if they are bigger than the root, it takes the root out, puts the new element, and shifts it down. At the end, the complexity is `O(log(n) * m)`.

Answer (score 0):

For heapq.nlargest(k, n), the complexity would be n + k*logn.

First heapify the iterable in n time, then pop the topmost element (given this is a max heap), and sift up the the heap until position 0. This will take log n time. We will repeat this k times. So the complexity here becomes k * logn.

If k is large, the complexity is decided by the latter part klogn, however, for smaller values of k, the complexity is decided by the former O(n). E.g. O(n + 3logn) where n is large becomes O(n).